# WPF popup capturing mouse doubleclick events

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, popup, mouseevent

In my main application window, there are controls, each of which opens a popup that presents more controls to the user.

Other controls in the main application window have mousedoubleclick event handlers.  My problem is that when the a user double clicks in the popup, the controls behind the popup are receiving the mousedoubleclick events.

I've tried added a mousedoubleclick event handler to the popup's parent, and handling the event, but it still gets through to the main application window.

```
    private void ParentControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I've also tried invoking Popup.CaptureMouse() in a MouseEnter event handler in the popup, but the method always fails (returns false).

```
    void popup_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Popup popup = sender as Popup;
        bool success = popup.CaptureMouse();
    }
```

Are there any other ways to prevent the mouse events from firing in the main application window when the popup is open?

Comment: Jim, I couldn't seem to reproduce your problem. Just to clarify, when you mention a pop-up, is this a new Window form or is it a control within the main Window changing its visibility from Hidden/Collapse to visible.

Comment: By popup, I mean the Popup class.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx

Comment: on which control do you set the event handler on?

Comment: Post your popup code both xaml and cs!!

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm getting the same problem. I've tried using the Preview... version of the mouse events on the control (a DataGrid) that is underneath the popup, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score -2):

Easy!  Instead of using the control's **MouseDoubleClick** event

```
private void myControl_MouseDoubleClick(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("MouseDoubleClick on control");

}
```

use the **PreviewMouseDoubleClick** event.

```
private void myControl_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(System.Object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("PreviewMouseDoubleClick on control");

}
```

Now double-clicking on your control will not also invoke the parent's DoubleClick event.

Comment: This answer does not address the OP's desire to capture the DoubleClick event on the popup and not the control underneath it.